# Silex ActiveRecord models loading

Tags: php, activerecord, namespaces, autoload, silex

I'm trying to use [PHP ActiveRecord](http://phpactiverecord.org/) with [Silex](http://silex.sensiolabs.org/), but something strange is happening with models autoloading:

```
// index.php
<?php require_once __DIR__.'/../vendor/autoload.php';

$app = new Silex\Application();

ActiveRecord\Config::initialize(function ($cfg) {
  $cfg->set_model_directory(__DIR__.'/../model');
  // ...
});

$app->get('/', function () {
  $page = App\Model\Page::all();
  // return ...;
});

// ../model/Page.php
<?php namespace App\Model;

class Page extends \ActiveRecord\Model {

}
```

When I'm opening a page, it says that "Class App\Model\Page not found".

If I manually `require '../model/Page.php'` - it works.
If I remove namespace from `../model/Page.php` and use it like usual class:

```
$page = Page::all();
```

it works again.

What's wrong with the namespaces?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the code you supplied above your **model** directory is written in lower case characters and when you use the class you use `App\Model\Page`. Change your directory from **model** to **Model**. You shall also check if your custom classes are correctly loaded by the `autoload.php` script. If that is not the case you have to update the **composer.json** file. Here is a simple example:

```
    {
    "require": {
        "silex/silex": "~1.0",
        "silex/web-profiler": "~1.0",
        "monolog/monolog": ">=1.0.0",
        "symfony/monolog-bridge": "~2.3",
        ...
    },
    "autoload": {
        "psr-0": {
            "HERE_GOES_YOUR_CUSTOM_NAMESPACE": "DIRECTORY_OF_NAMESPACE"
        }
    }
}
```

**Also do not forget to update the composer after edition of your project settings!**

Comment: Thank you! Adding autoloading to `composer.json` helped. But why should I manually define namespaces? Aren't they supposed to define automatically when including the file with `require`?

Comment: Yes, they should. In your example (or at least from the posted part) you did not actually include your file. To include it you should have something like 'require_once "/../model/Page.php"'. Including it in the composer just does that for you, so I highly recommend you using this method. It will automatically load all classes from the specified folders, so you don't have to worry when adding new classes. Otherwise you must manually add each new PHP file you create.

Comment: Well, I was actually including file with require… Thank you for your help!